# when running spark mllib kmeans, What is the role of each stage on website?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means

I try to use the spark mllib kmeans, but the job is hanging on the stage "collectAsMap at KMeans.scala:302". My code is writen by python.
could some one tell me what is happening on every stage such as "collect at KMeans.scala:436","aggregate at KMeans.scala:404","collectAsMap at KMeans.scala:302"
[here is the jobs picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIuMe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means is an iterative algorithm, where in each iteration points are assigned to the nearest centroid and centroids are updated based on the assigned points. This process is repeated until certain quality metric is satisfied. Initial centroids are computed using one of the number of possible methods including random centroids and K-means||.

In Spark, each iteration consist of aggregation where new centroids are computed and `collectAsMap` where data is fetched to the driver and broadcasted  to be used in the next iteration.

The second part corresponds to parallel initialization using K-means||